# ¿Cómo partir una imagen en muchas imágenes? en R

Tags: r

Tengo una imagen de tamaño 5400x2700, y lo que quiero hacer es partir esa imagen en muchas imágenes de tamaño 100x100.
¿cuál es la manera más rápida de hacer esto? ¿hay algún paquete de R que podría hacerlo muy rápido?

Estoy haciendo de la siguiente forma:

```
# img_matrix, matriz de tamaño 5400x2700
# m_100, matriz de tamaño 100x100
m_100 = matrix( rep( 0, len=10000), nrow = 100)
m_split = split(img_matrix, m_100)
```

Pero esto me da error "**...data length is not a multiple of split variable**"

Cualquier ayuda sería muy apreciada. Gracias

Comment: Me parece que esto es lo que necesitas. No lo he probado del todo, pero si necesitas algún ejemplo, lo podría hacer. http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/spatstat/html/split.im.html

Comment: Primero lo que hago es obtener la imagen original como una matriz, y luego particionar en trozos de igual tamaño. Aún estoy sin resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se pueden "cortar" manualmente mediante bucles, más bien es seleccionar y guardar en un nuevo objeto. Quizás no es el método más elegante ni el más rápido, pero funciona.

```
img_matrix <- matrix(1:14580000,nrow = 5400, ncol = 2700, byrow = T)

fila.ini <- seq(from=1,to=5301,by=100)
fila.fin <- seq(from=100,to=5400,by=100)

col.ini <- seq(from=1,to=2601,by=100)
col.fin <- seq(from=100,to=2700,by=100)

lista.matrices <- list()

for(i in 1:54){
  lista.matrices[[i]] <- list()
  for(j in 1:27)
    lista.matrices[[i]][[j]] <- img_matrix[fila.ini[i]:fila.fin[i],col.ini[j]:col.fin[j]]
}
```

Por ejemplo, el índice `lista.matrices[[2]][[3]]` corresponde a las filas 101:200 y a las columnas 201:300.

Comment: Gracias @aldo_tapia. Aún tengo una duda, ¿porqué le pone 1:54 y 1:27 en el bucle?

Comment: @user5672720 porque al ser divisiones de 100x100, el bucle debe recorrer la matriz dividiendo las filas en 54 unidades y las columnas en 27, 1:54 o 1:27 es para que vaya de 1 en 1 hasta llegar al 54 y al 27, respectivamente.